# Famous and old method getColor (int id) is deprecated. Api 23

Tags: android

I normally keep static color values in  res/values/colors.xml, as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <color name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</color>
 </resources>
```

I used them like:-

By xml:

```
 android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
```

By Java:

```
 textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

But what i found on http://developer.android.com/, is

```
 public int getColor (int id)

 Added in API level 1
 This method was deprecated in API level 23.
```

Then finally i want to ask how to use `(R.color.colorPrimary)` without any deprecation?
 Every help will be appreciated.

Thanks to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then finally i want to ask how to use (R.color.colorPrimary) without
>   any deprecation?

using [ContextCompat.getColor()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html). E.g.

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

From the doc

> Returns a color associated with a particular resource ID Starting in
>   M, the returned color will be styled for the specified Context's
>   theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot Blackbelt